nvidia container toolkit not working with docker-desktop Debian 12
I spent a day trying to figure out how to get nvidia container toolkit work in runtime in docker containers on docker-desktop Debian 12.
without docker-desktop, docker works fine with GPUs. any idea?

$ docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all ubuntu
nvidia-smi docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device
driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].

its@lisa:~/.docker$ docker info Client:  Version:    25.0.2  Context:  desktop-linux  Debug Mode: false  Plugins:   buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.13.1-desktop.1
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx   compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.26.1-desktop.1
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose   debug: Get a shell into any image or container. (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.0.27
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-debug   dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.2
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev   extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.23
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension   feedback: Provide feedback, right in your terminal! (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.4
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-feedback   init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.1.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-init   sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom   scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.6.3
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 26.0.0
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 nvidia runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.6.22-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 48
 Total Memory: 186.5GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 01b20dc4-06ba-4ec5-9bc8-7d6197d3130d
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Labels:
  com.docker.desktop.address=unix:///home/its/.docker/desktop/docker-cli.sock
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile

